# Управление звуком из delphi

Tags: delphi

Привет Всем! Мне нужно узнать, как из программы на delphi управлять звуком компьютера?

Comment: Громкость регулировать? Файл проиграть? Сгенерировать сэмпл? Применить эффект? 

Что именно вы хотите?

Comment: http://mirella8.ru/ если этот сайт делал ты, то не нужно больше заниматься WEBом. я долго ждал пока он загрузится, потом выставил нужную кодировку, она на всех страницах у тебя разная. Занимайся системным программированием в Delphi. Web - не нужно :)

Comment: http://mirella8.ru/ - это не мой сайт, а сайт моего друга я у него только там местечко беру. Мне нужно управлять громкостью компьютера

Comment: все равно бросай web :) или бери себе нормальный свой хостинг.

Comment: @Shrek долгим ты подразумеваешь свой Интернет, а не хостинг =) (Без обид)

Comment: я вообще-то с подсмыслом написал. ты не поймешь (без обид)

Comment: Я то все понял, а вот ты...все короче хватит это форум по "Железкам" а не перерикания друг с другом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Генерация звукового сигнала функция `beep;`

Comment: А при чем здесь регуляция громкости?

Comment: @insolor ты про что ?

Comment: Цитирую - как из программы на delphi управлять звуком компьютера...

Тоже не понял

Comment: ппц я вообще ничего не понимаю

Comment: Цитирую: "Мне нужно управлять громкостью компьютера"(5 часов назад) Миха Николаев
Ответ: "Генерация звукового сигнала...". Ответ принят:)

Comment: дурдом "Байтики и битики" )))

Answer (score 1):

Просмотрел в одном регуляторе громкости функции, импортируемые из WINMM.DLL, вот их список:

```
mixerGetLineInfo
mixerGetDevCaps
mixerGetNumDevs
mixerGetControlDetails
mixerSetControlDetails
mixerOpen
mixerGetLineControls
mixerClose
```

Приставка mixer как-бы говорит нам (по крайней мере мне), что они как-то связаны с регуляцией громкости. В остальном, Гугл в помощь.

P.S. вот, нагуглил пример кода: ["Как работать с микшером?"](http://www.delphimaster.ru/articles/mixer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Что вы стебетесь над Михаилом? Разве не понятно, что он хочет узнать, как регулировать громкость компьютера, а не управление сигналами типа beep. Там вроде какие-то API функции. Я вы тоже хотел почитать ответы по этому вопросу.

Comment: Для таких ответов как у вас существуют комментарии ;)